# QCustomPlot : grid display without any axes

Tags: qcustomplot

I need to display a grid in a QCustomPlot but without any axes visible.
This doesn't seems possible right now but I would like to know other opinions.

How I'm enabling grid right now :

```
plot->xAxis->setVisible(false);
plot->xAxis->grid()->setVisible(true);
plot->replot();
```

But the grid is not displayed.

I think it has to do with the fact that the grid is contained in the axis, and since the axis is not visible, the grid won't be displayed.

Does anyone know a solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you a bit. If you declare a transparent pen with 0 width (just in case :D) you can get rid of the axis and the ticks. They are not gone but you can't see them. You can set a transparent pen for the labels if you don't want to see them as well. Maybe someone can expand on how to get rid of the minor ticks.

```
QPen penclear;
penclear.setStyle(Qt::SolidLine);
penclear.setWidth(0);
penclear.setColor(QColor(1,1,1,1));

plot->xAxis->setBasePen(penclear);
plot->yAxis->setBasePen(penclear);
plot->xAxis->setTickPen(penclear);
plot->yAxis->setTickPen(penclear);
```